# Doctrine 2 and Postgres, serial field on non primary key columns

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

How can I use serial datatype in Doctrine 2 on non primary key columns?

Doctrine can use serial column as primary key with *generator strategy* set to SEQUENCE or IDENTITY but generator can not be used on non primary key columns.

I have table like this:

```sql
create table test (
    id integer not null generated by default as identity, 
    order serial
)
constraint test_pk primary key (id)
```

Doctrine entity:

```
App\Entity\Test:
    type: entity
    table: test

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: SEQUENCE
            sequenceGenerator:
                sequenceName: test_id_seq
    fields:
        order:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            column: '"order"'
```

What I want is that when I insert new row into this table, I don't have to specify order explicitly but db should take care of it.

In principle resulting sql code should look like this:

```sql
insert into test (DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

Without any configuration, doctrine try to insert null into column "order" resulting in error "can't insert null value into not null field"

### **What I tried**

I tried to set default value for "order" property inside php entity class, like this:

```php
private $order = 'DEFAULT'
```

but that erred out as "invalid syntax for integer"

Then I tried to put options into yaml definition like this:

```
fields:
        order:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            column: '"order"'
            options:
                default: DEFAULT
```

That did't make any difference.

Than I tried to make custom type named order but that failed too.

Code for custom type:

```php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class OrderType extends Type
{
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'order';
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        return 'DEFAULT';
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'DEFAULT';
    }

    public function canRequireSQLConversion(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'serial';
    }
}
```

This ends in error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" which is problem with method convertToDatabaseValueSQL. When I comment it out and use default implementation, error "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "DEFAULT""

It still quote word DEFAULT but I need it to be not quoted, it must used as keyword not as string.

I think custom type should work shomehow. In old Zend Framework v1 there was class Zend_Db_Exp which when used in sql statements was not quoted and value was used as is. I think I need something similar here.

### **Version info**

PHP 7.3

Postgres 11

Doctrine ORM 2.6 (I'll upgrade if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB trigger can be used to manage misbehaving clients, in this case Doctrine 2 based app.

Create trigger function:

```
create or replace function public."t_setDefaultValueOnOrderField"()
    returns trigger as
$body$
declare
    fq_table_name text := '"' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '"' || '.' || '"' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '"';
    sequence_name text := pg_get_serial_sequence(fq_table_name, 'order');
begin
    if NEW.order is null then
        NEW.order := nextval(sequence_name);
    end if;

    return NEW;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

And attach it to table:

```sql
create trigger "setDefaultValueOnOrderField"
    before insert
    on public.test
    for each row
execute procedure public."t_setDefaultValueOnOrderField"();
```

This is an ad hoc trigger for order field only, it may be adapted to handle any serial field present in target table.

---

**Until better solution is found, this will remain as accepted answer.**